# Windows 10 and hardware upgrade: strange behaviour after safe usb unplugging, that leads to data corruption on all hard drives

Tags: windows, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I recently upgraded several components in my PC, including the motherboard (ASUS Prime x670-p), RAM, GPU (Nvidia 1070 to Nvidia 4090), and CPU (Intel i7-6700k to AMD Ryzen 9 7950x). My previous setup included 2 SATA SSDs and 3 SATA HDDs. Right after the upgrade, I received a package from China containing my new Anycubic 3D printer from an official seller. This is important because I started encountering issues immediately after connecting the provided SD card with a card reader to my upgraded system.

The SD card has an unreadable name, some useful files, and one large file that seems to be corrupted. While working with this SD card, I noticed that reading, writing, and formatting were functional. However, when I attempted to safely remove the card, nothing happened. Even after physically disconnecting it, the disk still showed as present in the system but wouldn't function. Following this, my computer started exhibiting strange behavior: websites wouldn't load, applications installed on the C drive hung, and on the next boot, their configs were partially filled with NUL-values. As any other saved files. Although the computer didn't freeze, the UI remained active, playing animations, but opening new apps resulted in nothing. Furthermore, files that were moved or copied during this state (on any drives) disappeared upon the next reboot.

I suspect it could be a motherboard issue, either hardware-related or due to drivers, or possibly an issue with the SATA cables.

What are the possible reasons behind these behaviors and how I can investigate further?

And the main question: **how to fix that?**

Additional information:

- I have the latest version of "Avast!" installed and active.
- Windows is installed on an SSD using MBR.
- SATA disks S.M.A.R.T. is OK
- If I pull USB device without safe removing it first - everything is seems to be OK.
- No error messages were given; the system becomes unresponsive during the described issues.

Troubleshooting steps I've taken:

- Tried different USB ports and storage devices, all causing the same behavior.
- Switched SATA cables between the two SSDs.

Troubleshooting steps I will take:

- I will try GPT and clean windows install (right after new NVE ssd will arrive)

[Config with NULs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWxKx.png)

Comment: What error? Edit your question instead of commenting

Comment: *Windows is installed on an SSD using MBR*, why? This in itself can be a problem (it forced a Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" installation in the worst hardware to which you can get away with it). Pretty much everything since 2012 expects any Windows 8.x or newer to be properly installed in UEFI mode and that. for Windows, implies GPT.

Comment: This Windows installation has been with me since Windows 7 and lately was updated to Windows 10.

Comment: I would think that this extensive hardware upgrade is more in cause of your problems than sudden software collapse.

Comment: *since Windows 7 and lately was updated to Windows 10* So it's time to install fresh and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I installed Windows 11 on a new SSD with GPT, and everything works fine right now.

It seems that the issue was somehow related to a software problem, possibly driver conflicts.